# magento 2 disable module from backend

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3

Hi i am new to magento and currently learning custom module for most viewed product and the module works great.  now i have added a system.xml file below is the image.

[image]

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="netsmartz" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Netsmartz</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="mostviewed" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Most Viewed</label>
            <tab>netsmartz</tab>
            <resource>Netsmartz_Mostviewed::mostviewed_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Module Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Module Name</label>
                    <comment>
                        Enable the module to get the most viewed sorting option in frontend
                    </comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>   
                <Netsmartz_Mostviewed>
                        <general>
                            <use_cdn>1</use_cdn>
                                <display_text>Most Viewed</display_text>
                        </general>
                </Netsmartz_Mostviewed>
    </default>
</config>
```

now i want that when i hit module disable to no my module should be disable anyone have any idea how to achieve this.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work automatically.
What you can do is to wrap in all the methods that affect the core funtionality from your module in an `if` statement.

```
private $scopeConfig; //this shold be an instance of \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
public function doSomething()
{
    if ($this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag('path_to/your/config_field')) {
        //do what the method should do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your System.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="netsmartz" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Netsmartz</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="mostviewed" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Most Viewed</label>
            <tab>netsmartz</tab>
            <resource>Netsmartz_Mostviewed::mostviewed_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Module Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Module Name</label>
                    <comment>
                        Enable the module to get the most viewed sorting option in frontend
                    </comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

in Your  Vendor\Module\Helper\Data.php

```
    <?php
    namespace My\Module\Helper;

    class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
    {
       const MODULE_ENABLE = "mostviewed/mostviewed/enable";

       public function getDefaultConfig($path)
       {
           return $this->scopeConfig->getValue($path, \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
       }

       public function isModuleEnabled()
       {
           return (bool) $this->getDefaultConfig(self::MODULE_ENABLE);
       }
     }
```

Now Any of you file where you want to put Module enable disable condition

```
<?php
 protected $_dataHelper;

 public function __construct(
        \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $dataHelper
    ) {
        $this->_dataHelper = $dataHelper;
    }

    public function canShowBlock()
    {
        if($this->_dataHelper->isModuleEnabled()){
          // Your On Module Enabled Code
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what would be the path of the Block file

Comment: i just gave you an example.. you can this function anywhere.. to set condition

Comment: check my updated answer